# web-1.log vs web.stdout.log in AWS cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We have deployed a Spring Boot application to EC2 instances using Elastic Beanstalk. Also using network load balancer max upto 2 EC2 instances.

As per AWS documentation, for Java SE when we push logs to cloudwatch through Elastic BeanStalk, it creates a log file by naming web-1.log (path: `/aws/elasticbeanstalk/env-name/var/log/web-1.log`)

When I created another beanstalk application environment, there I see another log is getting created web.stdout.log in CloudWatch (path: `/aws/elasticbeanstalk/Boost-env-2-4/var/log/web.stdout.log`) instead of web-1.log

I do not know what configuration I missed here or any configuration change I should make.

Please your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using two different platform versions. First one based on Amazon Linux while the second one is based on Amazon Linux 2.